# Determining what font series are available

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I have a file `agaramond.map` which contains lines like the following:

```
pads8r AGaramond-Semibold "TeXBase1Encoding ReEncodeFont" <8r.enc <pads8a.pfb
```

Through trial and error, I have found out that I can select this particular semibold series with

```
\fontfamily{pad}\fontseries{sb}\selectfont
```

Is there an automated way of listing all combinations of `\fontfamily`, `\fontseries` and `\fontshape`? I don't know how to select a few of the cuts appearing in my .map files.

Comment: Check the `.fd`-file.

Comment: Excellent! In case anyone is wondering, it is located in `tex/latex/psnfss`

Comment: in that directory is the file `t1pag.fd` and not `t1pad.fd`

Comment: Well, on my system it is called `8rpad.fd`

Comment: Use `xelatex` or `lualatex` and `fontspec` instead of `pdflatex` and `nfss`.

Comment: If it were only up to me and I didn't have to collaborate or submit TeX files through automated submission systems, I would switch to luatex. Alas, that is not the case.

Answer (score 3):

have a look into the font definition file, eg:
http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/tex-new/share/texmf/tex/latex/agaramon/t1pad.fd

it lists all defined combination.

Comment: Could you expand your answer in order to apply to all fonts, not just this specific one?